# Disable link from div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm working on a portfolio site that uses Masonry and links each grid element to the full-size image using jQuery (adds link to entire div).

Certain grid elements are not supposed to link anywhere so I'm wondering whether its possible to remove the link for those elements without touching the original code. They each have their own class, which could be used as a selector.

I though of **remove()** or **empty()** but it doesn't work since I don't want to remove the div, I only want to disable the link that is associated with it.

**Code**

Sorry, its a massive file where the HTML is build via JS as well. Here is the complete file for those that have time on their hands to go through it: http://jsbin.com/UMILIXi/1/edit?js,output

The part that creates the element template is here:

```
//ITEM IMAGE TEMPLATE
                item: '<% if(item.gridInternalLink){ %>\
                <div class="' + o.itemClass + ' gridTextBox gridInternalLink" style="width:<%= width %>px;">\
                <p><%= item.gridTextBox %></p>\
                <% }else if(item.gridExternalLink){ %>\
                <div class="' + o.itemClass + ' gridTextBox gridExternalLink" style="width:<%= width %>px;">\
                <p><%= item.gridTextBox %></p>\
                <% }else if(item.gridNoLink){ %>\
                <div class="' + o.itemClass + ' gridTextBox gridNoLink" style="width:<%= width %>px;">\
                <p><%= item.gridTextBox %></p>\
                <% } else if(item.gridVideoLink){ %>\
                <div class="' + o.itemClass + '" style="width:<%= width %>px;">\
                <%= item.gridVideoLink %>\
                <% }else{ %>\
                <div class="' + o.itemClass + '" style="width:<%= width %>px;">\
                <img src="<%= item.image %>" width="<%=width%>"/>\
                <div class="' + o.itemInfoClass + '"><div class="' + o.itemTextClass + '">\
                <% if(item.link){ %><a href="<%= link %>" rel="<%= rel %>" title="<%= title %>"><% } %>\
                <div class="text-wrapper">\
                <% if(item.cat){ %>\
                <h3 class="post-info"><%=item.cat%></h3>\
                <% } %>\
                <h2><%= item.title %></h2></div><div class="view-gallery">\
                <% if(item.imgnum){ %><span class="item-num"><%= item.imgnum %></span><% } %>\
                <span class="grid-gallery-icon<%= additionalClass %>"></span><span class="view-text"><%= viewText %><span class="more-arrow">&raquo;</span></span>\
                </div><% if(item.link){ %></a><% } %>\
                </div></div>\
                <% } %>\
                </div>'
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and JS code to the question.

Comment: Post the HTML at least

Answer (score 0):

You could simply prevent the default action of the link:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.linkClass', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I thought of that, but then I would disable the link on ALL elements. I only need to disable the link on certain elements.

Comment: @domdev - In your question you say *"They each have their own class, which could be used as a selector"* - which I assume you can use as the selector above. (replace `.linkClass`)

Comment: Yeah sorry, you're right. I just gave it a shot but it didn't work unfortunately. I will keep trying -- thank you for your response though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" *mean*? Errors, everything was disabled..?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to remove href for div

```
$('.linkClass').attr('href','#');
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
  $('div.yourClassName').append('<div id="over" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

The point where you are conditionally adding the anchor tag, can you not check for the `gridNoLink` property as well and accordingly add an anchor or a span?

Something like:

```
<% if(item.gridNoLink) { %>
  <span>
<% } else if(item.link){ %>
  <a href="<%= link %>" rel="<%= rel %>" title="<%= title %>">
<% } %>\
<div class="text-wrapper">\
...desired markup
</div>
<% if(item.gridNoLink) { %>
  </span>
<% } else if(item.link){ %>
  </a>
<% } %>\
```

This way no additional script would be required to handle tiles with no link. Also, it will ensure that you don't end up with anchor tags that change the cursor on hover but don't trigger any action on click.